# Query about LRU Replacement Strategy - Confusion on Page Selection

Tags: page-replacement

I've been exploring the Least Recently Used (LRU) page replacement strategy, and I've come across a point of confusion that I would appreciate some clarification on.

As I understand it, in LRU, the page with the lowest (oldest) last access time is considered the least recently used and is a candidate for replacement. However, when I examine the provided page table with last access times:

- Page 1: Last accessed time - 94
- Page 2: Last accessed time - 23
- Page 3: Last accessed time - 101
- Page 4: Last accessed time - 44
- Page 5: Last accessed time - 23
- Page 6: Last accessed time - 64

It seems that Page 5 has the more recent last access time (23) compared to Page 3 (101). According to my understanding, a lower value in last access time implies a more recent access.

Could someone kindly help me understand why Page 3 is considered the correct answer for replacement instead of Page 5? I want to make sure I have a clear grasp of the LRU strategy.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the times are stored like usual seconds, with smaller numbers being earlier. That’s why first access time is always less than last access time.

Answer (score 0):

Time starts at zero. Page 5 was last accessed at $t=23$, while page 3 was last accessed at $t=101$. Suppose rn is $t=102$, which do you think is the least recently used page?